# Perl String replacement issue

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, double-quotes

I have a string as shown below,

```
$str = 'dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"'
```

I want to replace:

```
dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"
```

to

```
!dev-phase-to-improve=""
```

wondering how can i do that my code is some thing like as shown below,

```
$rc_link =~ s/'dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"/!dev-phase-to-improve=""/ig;
```

but it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: In other words I want final value to be   !dev-phase-to-improve == "" from existing dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"

Comment: That's not what you said in the question. Which is it?

Comment: You do not have a `'` in your string, therefore that regex can never match.

Comment: Any special handling for single or double quote that i need to do  at s/'dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"'/!dev-phase-to-improve=""/ig;  ?

Comment: Where the pattern is the complete source string, you can simply replace one value with the new one (there's no need for a `s///` command).  So, since you're probably not doing it just for the sheer hell of it, what does the source string really look like, and how flexible is the matching?  You have `ig` qualifiers after the `s///`, so apparently the string can repeat in the source, and the match may need to be case-insensitive.  That's legitimate, but not the impression the question gives.  In other words, it is not yet clear what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,     $rc_link= 'dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"';
$rc_link =~ s/dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"/!dev-phase-to-improve=""/ig;
print $rc_link ;

Comment: @Ammad `!dev-phase-to-improve=""` is not the same string as `!dev-phase-to-improve == ""`.

Comment: I suggest you just write `$rc_link = '!dev-phase-to-improve == ""'`

Comment: You do not have a `'` in your string, therefore that regex can never match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, check out this

```
my $str = 'dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"';
$str=~ s/dev-phase-to-improve == "NOTEQUAL"/\!dev-phase-to-improve=""/g;
print $str."\n";
```